# Any Superheros by Choice?

Tags: super-hero

It seems like most superheros are either born that way (Superman, Wonder Woman, Aquaman and Ancient Mariner, for example), or are made into a superhero without their consent (Fantastic Four, Hulk, Green Lantern and Spiderman, for example).  Many of the born superheros are outsiders living in human society and trying to make good (like the X-Men and the others I listed earlier).

I've found five exceptions, but, except for one, those seem created by outside influences:

- Batman (but he has serious issues and it springs from the trauma of his parents' murder)
- Ironman (but he had no choice to have to put the power source in his chest and it seems circumstances kept him going as a superhero)
- M.A.N.T.I.S (from the TV series) (He makes the exo-skeleton on his own, but is still driven by a need for revenge on the bad guys)
- Captain America (he volunteered for the experiment, but had no idea what it would do to him)
- Green Arrow (who seems the only superhero by choice that I can find)

Other than the Green Arrow, are there any superheros that basically looked around, decided, "I **want** to do something to help, and I have the money or ability to do it!" ?  Even the ones I listed above who made a choice to be a superhero seem to have been driving.

Are there any others besides Green Arrow who are superheros by choice?

(I'm not asking for a long list, so please don't get upset and say it's a list question.  Just an example or two will prove to me Green Arrow isn't a fluke.)

Comment: I think you're wrong to dismiss Superman.  He arrived on Earth with the super-abilities, but he _chose_ to use them for good.  He could have been the tyrant to end all tyrants.

Comment: @KyleJones but he didn't choose to gain them.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a case of (like with one of my recent questions) where it clearly stated it's not asking for a list but people are MAKING it into a list by refusing to read. :(

Comment: Well, we've gotten the example or two that Tango wanted, so those of you with the 3k reps can close the question if you like.  But I find the question interesting and would like to see if more examples will turn up.  I had to rack my brain to come up with Batgirl.

Comment: Along with @KyleJones, I would be interested in other possible superheros.  I'm not so sure I'd count someone like Batman, since he didn't so much make a choice as succumb to an obsession and need for revenge.

Comment: Just because you're not asking for the complete list doesn't make this not a list question. If anything, this makes the answers even less useful since they're guaranteed to be incomplete. As a rule, the answer to “is there any other example” questions is always yes anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: It take only one exception to disprove the rule.  If you're looking for proof that a theory is wrong, then all you need is one counter-example.  In my case, for example, this ties in to some work I'm doing as a writer, so getting any proof it's wrong is a big help -- and it leaves it as proof for anything looking for this in the future.  In other words, even one answer was **very** helpful to me, even if not by your standards.

Comment: They are all by choice. You don't wake up or get powers and think you should continue the life of a criminal. Still, you're asking for a short list, not a long list, of names. If you're looking for what motivates a character, that's probably better for Writers

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: If that were true (that people didn't get powers and think they should continue a life of crime), then there'd be no super-villains.  I don't want to ask writers, because I'm concerned with what we, as readers/viewers see.

Comment: Wait, Bruce Wayne didn't choose to become Batman?  Tony Stark didn't choose to become Iron Man?  The devices of them becoming superheroes don't eliminate their choices.  Bruce Wayne easily could have just accepted his parents' deaths.  Tony Stark easily could have chose not to make the Iron Man armor.  Even Captain America decided to use his abilities for good.  As did Spider-Man, Superman, and wonder Woman.  Just because they have the abilities or tools or motivation to be a superhero, that doesn't mean they had to become heroes.

Comment: I thought "the Guardians" gave each Green Lantern the choice whether to accept the assignment.  And afterward, they can choose any time to not wear the ring nor recharge it.

Comment: I think your phrasing should be "Are there any heroes that sought out being a hero, rather than being thrust into it through some course of events where they didn't intend it to be the outcome, or initiate the events that lead to them being a hero of their own accord" And the answer to that is... Tim Drake. This is why I consider him one of the only heroes in DC. He not only chose to go down that path, but it has literally been to his detriment and he has continued, where as others the detriment is the cause where they lose things allowing them to being heroes more easily.

Comment: Ant-Man (Comic Version)? While the movie rather pressed him into service through circumstance, in the comics Scott Lang is under no real obligations to be Ant-Man, he's just given the opportunity and he goes for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the heros in Watchmen? Doctor Manhattan is a traditional superhero, and I guess he falls into the "forced on them" category, but most of the heros are just normal humans.

Answer (score 4):

Batgirl.  Looking at the Wikipedia article there were many incarnations, but the Barbara Gordon one that I remember got started by intervening in a kidnapping.  She kicked some kidnapper butt one night and decided that she liked it.

Answer (score 3):

The Green Hornet seems to have been a choice although the origin stories are murky for some story lines.

Doctor Strange chose to learn the mystic arts.

There are a number of heroes that, like Batman, chose the superhero path for vengeance, such as The Punisher, Daredevil and Rorschach.

Comment: I remember a little of Doctor Strange from years ago, but had forgotten him.  And didn't realize it was a choice for the Green Hornet.  I'm still on the fence, on my end, about whether vengeance is a choice or an obsession that one can't control.  I'd say that with Batman, it's definitely out of his control.

Comment: For the most populat GH storyline, the TV one, Britt Reid's father was convicted of a crime. He dies in jail before being exhonerated, and young Britt's faith in the system dies, so he decides to provide a helping (green) hand.

Answer (score 1):

The three (deceased) [Grasshoppers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grasshopper_%28comics%29) from the GLA continuity fit the bill:

The first is *Doug Taggart*

> ...an employee of Roxxon Oil who pines after fellow Roxxon researcher Cindy Shelton...Though it is never so stated, the implication is that Roxxon designed and built the gear which is the source of Grasshopper's powers.

Then there is *Neil Shelton*

> Neil Shelton was a security guard for Roxxon who gained use of the Grasshopper suit some time after Doug Taggert's death.

The last is Unnamed, but the implication is that he/she also chose to be the Grasshopper.

Comment: If Batman is a "super"hero, then we need to clearly define "super."  He has talent/skill developed by training/exercise, like many of the others mentioned.  Maybe "powers" is what needs to be defined.  :-)